# Change the focus of a Dell WB3023 using Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have a Dell WB3023 webcam that I am using for a Python project. I am controlling it via Python but the autofocus is terrible. Is there a way where I can manually control it?

I have tried the code below in OpenCV but it doesn't work. The driver doesn't seem to be incompatible.

```
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS, 0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOCUS, 1)
```

Are there any other methods (doesnt have to be Open CV) that can allow me to change the focus of a webcam manually?

Comment: Did you try selecting Direct Show Driver in video capture. `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_index,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)`